# Finding the Quadratic Variation Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales, quadratic-variation

Let $X = X_t$ be an ito process

$X_t = X_0 + \frac{1}{3}t^3+\int_0^t e^s dB_s , t \geq 0$

and let $Y = Y_t$ also be an ito process

$Y_t = Y_0 + te^t+\int_0^t s^2 dB_s  ,t \geq 0$

How would I find the Quadratic Variation process $\langle X^2+Y^2 , XY \rangle$?

From what I understand I will need to apply Ito's formula at some point but my issue is i'm not quite sure when I need to apply Ito's formula.

This is much more complicated than other examples we have covered in class so any help is massively appreciated! :)

Comment: Try computing the dynamics of $X^2 + Y^2$ and $XY$, and use that to read off their covariation.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean just work $X^2+Y^2$ and $XY$ individually? i'm a little unsure as to how to do this, I'm guessing for $X^2+Y^2$ I need to apply Ito's Isometry individually and then add them?

Comment: I  meant you should find $d(X^2+Y^2)$ and $d(XY)$ by using Itô's lemma.

Comment: Would you be able to demonstrate how you would calculate one of these examples so I can have a go at computing the other, I find this topic extremely difficult